# One or more required office components failed to complete successfully error during uninstallation of SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, uninstallation

I am trying to uninstall SharePoint 2016 as it is consuming a lot of RAM (Requires 16 gb and I have only 8 gb of RAM). I want to install SharePoint 2013 on my system. But, whenever I am trying to uninstall it, I am getting one message as: "One or more required office components failed to complete successfully. For more information, consult the setup log file". I don't know, why this error message is coming. I checked some features like Configuration Wizard are still existing. Kindly, let me know how to remove SharePoint 2016 completely so that I can do a fresh installation of SharePoint 2013.

Thanks,

Purushottam

[image]

Comment: SharePoint 2013 will struggle on 8GB unless you’re doing development work only, and even then, it’s not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link to uninstall SharePoint - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/uninstall-sharepoint-server-2016

1. Take note to remove the language packs completely as well
2. I would also suggest to go for a reboot of the machine and then
   rerun the uninstall from the control panel.
3. Take a look at the setup log as well.
4. If none of the above works you can format the drive and reinstall
   the OS if you have the image handy .

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestion. Actually, I just stopped all the SQL services in services.msc and the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to stop all the SQL services in services.msc And the issue got resolved